# PHP echo <div> after every 8th element in foreach loop

Tags: php, html, foreach

```
<?php foreach ( $onecho['icons'] as $icon => $file ) : ?>
    <li class="play">
        <label>
            <img class="icon" src="<?php echo onecho_Class_Icon::getIconUrl($icon) ?>"/>
            <input type="radio" name="icon" value="<?php echo $icon ?>" />
       </label>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

What I am attempting is every 8(images) for the foreach is have it echo a div.

Comment: so... where is the attempt?

Comment: I want to echo "<div id="aaa"></div>" after 8 of the foreach.

Comment: Imagine you walked into a room full of people programming, stopped them all and then just shouted that. Would you expect one of them to know it was a question rather than a statement of fact, let alone know what your problem is?

Comment: @BenStephenson For some reason this made me chuckle

Comment: +1 to everyone that correctly answers this without knowing further details.

Comment: @jbnunn It's funny because you haven't upvoted anyone. Only I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a counter and echo the div when $i%8 == 0

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ( $onecho['icons'] as $icon => $file ) :
      $i++;
?>
<li class="play">
<label>
<img class="icon" src="<?php echo onecho_Class_Icon::getIconUrl($icon) ?>"/>
<input type="radio" name="icon" value="<?php echo $icon ?>" />
</label>
<?php if ($i%8 == 0): ?>
<div>My Div</div>
<?php endif;?>
</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop counter will do.

If it is divisible by 8, echo the div.

```
<?php
$i = 1;

foreach ( $onecho['icons'] as $icon => $file ) : 
    if ($i % 8 == 0 ) echo '<div>';
?>

<li class="play">
<label>
<img class="icon" src="<?php echo onecho_Class_Icon::getIconUrl($icon) ?>"/>
<input type="radio" name="icon" value="<?php echo $icon ?>" />
</label>
</li>
<?php
    if ($i % 8 == 0 ) echo '</div>';

    $i++;
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: $i should be initialized to one else you will get div when i =0 and when i = 8 (the ninth iteration)

Comment: @Orangepill Good spot.

Comment: @DanyCaissy Just use `arraykeys`

Comment: @DanyCaissy yeah it will.. he's not using the keys for the iterator... he is maintaining his own

Comment: @DanyCaissy But he is not, and given the level of question I think that lesson may be a way off.

Comment: Ah I read too quickly